# Dynamics of dielectric dipole during polarization?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, polarization, dielectric

When a dielectric material is placed in an exterior electric field, a process of polarization would occur.

[image]

During the stretching phase, does that happen uniformly(stretch evenly)or only in a specific direction(e.g. negative charge moving away from positive charge)?

[image: p]

Also, what limits the streching length per dipole? What limits it from going from $x$-$nm$ to $2x$-$nm$?-

Answer (score 1):

According to *An Introduction to Electrodynamics The Fourth Edition* by David Griffiths page 167, the positive nucleus and the electrons both move during polarization. So to your first question, the stretching is even: both move. On the same page, Griffiths states that the electron cloud and the nucleus reach a balance after they have become displaced by some distance. At this point, the force from the electron cloud to the nucleus balances the force of the external electric field on the nucleus and the electron cloud. If this external field is large enough, the electrons can be ripped from their nucleus.